# get value from Linq and put it in the tex box

Tags: asp.net

i have this code

```
MasterSoapClient sp = new MasterSoapClient();
MasterData[] lstMasterData = sp.GetActivityType(stid, null, 1);
grdEditActivityType.DataSource = lstMasterData;
grdEditActivityType.DataBind();
Session["opType"] = 2;

txtActivityCode.Text = lstMasterData.ToString();
txtActivityCode.DataBind();
```

here i called web service and put all data in this Gridview "grdEditActivityType "
and already workin 
but there is column of lstMasterData  i want to put it in the text box out of the grid 
how i can do this ?

Comment: Are you planning to concatenate all the rows or are you only outputting one row?

Answer (score 0):

txtActivityCode.Text is a Property that you can use to assign a text value to the TextBox.

If you use `txtActivity.Text = " some input ";` Your textbox will contain the text " some input ".
You don't need to Bind txtActivityCode afterwards.

Having this clarified the next step is to create the string you want using to assign to the text box.

```
string s = "";
foreach( var masterData in lstMasterData ) 
{
    s += masterData.SomeProperty; // s += masterData.ToString(); maybe, it depends on what do you want to put in the textbox;
}
txtActivityCode.Text = s;
```

And that's all.

I would suggest to start look more over ASP.NET tutorials to understand better how this framework works.